# Where do I get the package sr_control_gui?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install the `sr_control_gui` package into my ros-fuerte on ubuntu 12.04.

I installed the `sr_visualization` stack because `sr_control_gui` is part of the  stack (see [sr_control_gui](http://www.ros.org/wiki/sr_control_gui))

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-sr-visualization
```

but it is not in there. `roscd sr-visualization` works, `roscd sr_control_gui` doesn't.

Where can I get this package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45113/where-do-i-get-the-package-sr_control_gui?/) by [ricoj](https://answers.ros.org/users/3309/ricoj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2012-10-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ricoj](https://answers.ros.org/users/3309/ricoj/) on 2012-10-04**:
hmm.. but that does not help me. I need *sr_control_gui* to launch *cyberglove* (from the *sr-teleop* stack).

Running *roslaunch cyberglove cyberglove.launch* throws a *ResourceNotFound: sr_control_gui* error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay, I talked to the guy maintaining these packages.

It turns out they removed the package sr_control_gui from the stack and the dependency is a bug that is going to be fixed.

If someone is having the same problem right now, let me know and I'm going to share the hotfix.

---

Originally posted by [ricoj](https://answers.ros.org/users/3309/ricoj/) with karma: 18 on 2012-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on 2012-11-16**:
i was trying to run Running roslaunch cyberglove cyberglove.launch throws a ResourceNotFound: sr_control_gui error also, and gets the same problem, i don't know how to get the sr_control_gui

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To me it seems like the sr_visualization stack just provides a bunch of plugins for [rqt_gui](http://ros.org/wiki/rqt_gui) to interact with the shadow hand. Try:

```
rosrun rqt_gui rqt_gui
```

You should be able to find the shadow plugins in the `Plugins` menu.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1